# self.layer renderInContext:context in drawRect method gives Bad Access in ipad but not in simulator

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I am working in an app and in which i do the video recording. Now what i do is capture the images and then create the video the code is as follows

```
- (void) drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    NSDate* start = [NSDate date];

    CGContextRef context = [self createBitmapContextOfSize:self.frame.size];
    NSLog(@"context value %@",context);

    [self.layer renderInContext:context];

    CGImageRef cgImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
    UIImage* background = [UIImage imageWithCGImage: cgImage];
    CGImageRelease(cgImage);
    self.currentScreen = background;


    if (_recording) {
        float millisElapsed = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:startedAt] * 1000.0;
        [self writeVideoFrameAtTime:CMTimeMake((int)millisElapsed, 1000)];

    }

      float processingSeconds = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:start];
      delayRemaining = (1.0 / self.frameRate) - processingSeconds;


      [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(setNeedsDisplay) withObject:nil];

}
```

Now the problem is that the method is called recursively and when stop recording it gives me Exc_Bad_Access.

It works fine in simulatoor bot crash in  device, How can i solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn’t be doing this in `drawRect:`, the only reason to override `drawRect:` is to do some custom drawing (which you are not). You also shouldn’t call `setNeedsDisplay` on a background thread, this is a GUI method which can only be called from the main thread. Also depending on how your `createBitmapContextOfSize:` method and your environment you might need to release your bitmap context object.

Comment: when i use this setneedsdisplay on main thread the app gives me SIGBART  :[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array